# is it possible to setup dual user authentication to write files between removable media and host systems on a network

Tags: authentication, security, gpo

We have a Windows closed network (no internet) that also has Vsphere. I wanted to know if it's possible to setup something to trigger the credential input popup when trying to move files on/off a system with removable media. I also want that credential popup to require input from a different user in the same OU to allow the action.

I'm curious if this can be done through GPO directly or if there's 3rd party software that can do 2 person authentication enforcement